# Can not insert data into mysql data base from android application

Tags: php, android

I am working on my Android MySQL project and I have made my database on WAMP server2.0. Database name is "test". I used PHP for insert operation.

this is my code.

```
b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
findViewById(R.id.newslabel);
findViewById(R.id.timetable);
try{

    HttpClient httpClient =new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/swapnil/mycon.php");       
    if(httpPost != null)
        {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Connected";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }

    try
    {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name1.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id1.getText().toString()));


         httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

when i click on button my data does not insert into my database table.

this is my mycon.php file

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();



// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$name=$_POST['name'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
// mysql update row with matched pid
$result =mysql_query("insert into info(name, id) values ('$name', '$id')", $connect);
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

i could not find what was my mistake in this code. i just wnat to insert data from android applicaton to mysql database. please help me.

Comment: where is your $connect variable?

Comment: I would also suggest using PDO instead of mysql_query.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, i have solved my issue. [LINK](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php) check step 3 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id column is an INT.

Change

```
INSERT INTO info(name, id) VALUES ('$name', '$id')
```

to

```
INSERT INTO info(name, id) VALUES ('$name', $id)
```

You must not sourund `INT` values with `''`